# how to stop post back in button click where inside the click event if some condition is true

Tags: .net, asp.net

how to stop post back in button click where inside the click event if some condition is true

Comment: Since you use the phrase "post back", I assume you're using ASP.NET?

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is have your button call a javascript function from the `OnClientClick` event. You can then let this function check whatever condition you want. If this function returns true, postback will occur; if it returns false, postback will not occur. Example:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
function callPostBack()
{
    if (condition)       
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
</script>

<asp:Button  ID="Mybutton"  runat="server"  OnClientClick="return callPostBack();" Text="Button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just have the click_event return false.  Returning false will cancel the postback event.